# Is there a website that lists budget airlines for each country?

Tags: air-travel, budget

I'm looking for a list of budget airlines for each country. Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia has a pretty good list of budget airlines sorted per country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_low-cost_airlines
This might be very helpful to decide which airline to choose.

The flight search website [Whichbudget.com](http://www.whichbudget.com/) might also help. It specifically searches airfares at low-cost carriers.